# What's the right way to manage dependencies of dependencies for libraries in .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a .NET Framework project with a set of dependent assemblies. One of these assemblies has a dependency on a third assembly.

Project 1 depends on --> Assembly A which depends on --> Assembly B

What I would like to do is ensure that when Assembly A is deployed, Assembly B is included with that deployment. Is there a way to force that dependency check within Assembly A so that if Project 1 is fired up it will fail if Assembly B is not present with Assembly A?

Should I just include Assembly B with Project 1? What I don't like about this is there are no code references within Project 1 for Assembly B. It's misleading when reviewing the project as it's not apparent this dependency is needed because of Assembly A.

Comment: Is Assembly A referencing Assembly B through a project reference, dll reference, or NuGet package?

Comment: I believe if the dependent assembly is pulled in with your target assembly when referenced, then everything will be published, unless you go to the release folder and delete it manually.

Comment: this "should" happen automatically. that being said, the new publish wizard in VS 2019 has issues, and one of those can be that it doesn't properly build dependencies after temporarily switching to release mode. as a last resort you can put your solution into release mode, build your project, and then manually copy from the bin folder, making sure that all files are up to date.

Comment: Assembly A is referencing Assembly B through a dll reference

Comment: You can find tons of posts over the internet saying MSBuild failed to copy indirect assemblies over. It is hard to tell "the right way", as everyone might think differently. The best IMHO is Microsoft fixes those bugs, but you might prefer something else, like one of the workarounds https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=indirect+msbuild+references

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure author of NuGet that you've used to add "Assembly A" authored it properly and included references to all related NuGets correctly.
2. If you don't use NuGet to add "Assembly A" - request NuGet to be create for "Assembly A" and go to 1.